# Is it dangerous to print random pointers? (Windows 10, x64)

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, memory, ram

I created a program in C++ that creates a pointer to a variable, and then proceeds to read every byte in the my machine's memory as a character. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    unsigned long long i = 0;
    char start = 65;
    char* ptr = &start;
    while (1) {
        try {
            std::cout << *(ptr + i);
        } catch (...) {
            std::cout << "!";
        }
        i++;
        Sleep(atoi(argv[1]));
    }
}
```

When I run the program, the output changes; sometimes I get a few lines of gibberish, but other times I get pages' worth of output, amidst which I can find system information (e.g. directories and languages). This is cool. So cool, that I'm worried it might be potentially harmful to my system. Is there any risk in printing the contents of random pointers?

Also, my computer has made a notification noise twice in the past three minutes, and neither time did I receive a notification. It might just be a coincidence, but I'm getting spooked

Comment: even if you write to your random addresses in theory you shouldn't do any damage

Comment: @AlanBirtles Because the memory is volatile, and nothing will be changed on the disk?

Comment: Because windows shouldn't let you write to anything your program doesn't own

Comment: Printing random pointers (as stated in the question title) is fine, they are essentially integers. However dereferencing pointers and accessing objects they point to (in order to print or anything else) is allowed only when they really point at alive objects of compatible type. So the code presented in the question is totally broken and may lead to unexpected results, such as [time travel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

Comment: To print the value of the pointer (its contents), cast the pointer to a `void *`.  Printing the value of a pointer or assigning pointers to pointers is valid.  Dereferencing an invalid pointer (a pointer to an invalid location), is undefined behavior.

Comment: The program won’t read every character in your machine’s memory; at best it will read some of the characters in your process’s memory space before crashing.  The notification sounds are probably due to some of the bytes you are printing being coincidentally equal to the ASCII BEL character code.

Comment: @Alexandra *my computer has made a notification noise twice* -- *but I'm getting spooked* -- `std::cout << (char)7;` -- Do you hear a "notification" when that line is executed?

Comment: I've reopened this. While this could be a duplicate, those weren't the correct duplicate links (OP didn't ask if this is UB, they asked if this is dangerous or not, and even specified the platform).

Comment: There is a remote possibility that printing garbage to your terminal could cause a problem.  If for instance it supports [ANSI escape codes](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797), which include a "keyboard string" feature, then theoretically your program could output the escape code that redefines the `a` key to the string `format c:`.  More likely is that it outputs an escape code that just makes the terminal unusable (e.g. doesn't echo your keystrokes), which is annoying because you have to restart the terminal, but does no permanent harm.

Comment: You can use [`std::isprint`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint) to determine whether to print the character or a place-holder. For example: `char c = ptr[i]; if (!std::isprint((unsigned char)c)) c = '.'; std::cout << c;`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat *"if this is dangerous or not,..."* So are you saying/claiming that UB is not dangerous?

Comment: "proceeds to read every byte in the my machine's memory" no it doesn't.   Your program doesn't have access to every byte in your machine's memory.  Pointers don't point to addresses in system memory.  They point into their virtual address space.

Comment: @user12002570 Depending on the meaning of "dangerous". Can it crash your program or make it do weird things? Yes. Can it affect other processes or damage the hardware? Almost certainly no. A good answer would explain both the standard's point of view (nasal demons and all) and the practical effects of virtual addressing and so on. Being overdogmatic about UB (I'm not saying you are) doesn't make one a better programmer, it leads to nonsense questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77798143/2752075).

Comment: Depends what you mean by "dangerous". Dereferencing a "random pointer" (or adding an integral value  and dereferencing) causes undefined behaviour.   If you're just printing the result of dereferencing, you'll often get either junk data or (if the host system detects your program accessing memory outside its allocated address space) abnormal program termination. Neither trash memory used by other programs or the OS, but *can* be dangerous if your program uses the dereferenced values in calculations, and behaves differently based on result of those calculations.

Comment: @user12002570   Undefined behaviour is not necessarily dangerous.    People seem to equate undefined behaviour with things like program crashes, reformatting system drives, or electrocuting the end user (or, better, the developer).    Those can (notionally) happen.  But it is quite common for undefined behaviour to be benign or (in circumstances, such as a particular compiler that documents a particular useful behaviour with some construct that causes undefined behaviour) beneficial.

Comment: @Peter *"Undefined behavior means anything can happen(allowed to happen from standard's perspective) including but not limited to the program giving one's expected output. But never rely(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that have UB. The program may just crash."*

Answer (score 3):

No. OS assign a [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) before launching any process. Any access outside that address results in a [segfault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

So the program may keep reading all the random(maybe interesting) bytes in its address space until it gets a segfault.

References:

- [How do seg faults happen with virtual memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438660/how-do-seg-faults-happen-with-virtual-memory)